# In Bayesian modelling how to interpret hierarchical hyperparameters with regards to "borrowing"?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, uninformative-prior

With regards to hierarchical models I often see these referred to as groups borrowing information from each other e.g.

> It will be seen that the hierarchical model posterior estimates for one school borrows information from other schools

[source](https://bayesball.github.io/BOOK/bayesian-hierarchical-modeling.html)

I was hoping someone could explain where this interpretation comes from. As example lets say we fit the following model:

$$
\begin{align} 
x_{ij} &\sim N(\mu_i, \sigma) \\
\mu_i &\sim N(\mu', \tau) \\
\end{align}
$$

Where $\mu', \tau, \sigma$ are all parameters that we need to provide priors for.  My basic understanding is that:

- If we put a strongly informative prior on $\tau \to \infty$ then we are basically saying that the $\mu_i$ are independent e.g. there is no "borrowing"
- If we put a strongly informative prior on $\tau \to 0$ then we are basically saying that the $\mu_i = \mu$ e.g. they should all be regarded as coming from the same group with a singular mean.

However what does it mean if we put a weakly informative or non-informative prior on $\tau$ ? Does the parameter estimate of $\mu_i$ meaningfully impact the estimate of $\mu_j$? Or is this equivalent to modelling $\mu_i$ independently and then fitting $\mu'$ and $\tau$ to the $\mu_i$ as if they were fixed ?  That is, if we have a weakly informative prior is there any "borrowing" and if so how strong is it and what impact does this practically have ?

Comment: With your two limit cases for $\tau$ you've described fixed effects and random effects models, respectively. Any $\tau \in (0, \infty)$ just [generalizes this setup](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/120964).